# Is it safe to use "old" to mean "previous" for a person?

Tags: word-choice, offensive-language, ambiguity, meaning

Is it safe to use "*old*" to mean "*previous*" or "*former*" for something like "my old teacher"? Or is it a bit risky, because "*old*" also has a meaning with respect to age (i.e., chronologically gifted)?

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/old) doesn't give any warnings about "*old*" potentially causing offense. But should it be avoided in this context anyway?

Comment: I like this euphemism for _age_ "(ie chronologically gifted)". Despite its common use in everyday parlance, I'd avoid using _old_ to mean _previous/former_ around people who are particularly PC & who are prepared to take umbrage at everything they hear that might even remotely imply a negative meaning. All 5 of my "old wives" are much younger than I, except for the two who are "late". For most folks, perception is reality, even when they know it isn't (cognitive dissonance); and judgment is half of their alleged "right to freedom of expression", & self-righteous indignation, the other half.

Comment: @Bill Franke: How dare you.

Comment: @Mitch: Easy. Half nature & half nurture. I'm at my own mercy, and I seem to have none. Not for myself, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable. While I suppose that *old* could be misconstrued to mean *aged*, it's unlikely to be misinterpreted as such in context.

Here's a [dictionary confirmation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old):

> **7:** former
>   *his **old students***

A real-world example using variants of *old* and *former* to describe *students* and *teachers* can be [seen here](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110924104800AAX2qnp).

Comment: "in the provided context.": What context is provided in the question? For all purposes, the phrase could be followed by: ", not the younger one, I mean." providing the required "context".

Comment: @Kris Updated answer.

Comment: I cannot "update" the comment, but it stands, minus the word 'provided'. :) See: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/97652/14666

Comment: @Kris :) I'd love to split hairs with you. But I'll let Messrs. Webster & Merriam do that on my behalf :P

Comment: And indeed, if one were to refer to old-age teachers, or even students, surely one would use *elderly*.

Answer (score 3):

If they are your enemies and you must talk delicately, then say *former*. Otherwise, you are a-ok.

Answer (score -3):

Generally, *old* in the sense of *former* or *previous* is not used in such constructions at all. In the given context, the word *old* can only mean *aged*; *My old teacher* cannot be the opposite of *My new teacher*.

However, *old* is sometimes used in such expressions as *my old house* (to mean the *previous*), and *an old friend* (long-time friend).

On a different note, the use of *old* for *former* or *previous* is standard in some Oriental languages, where *old* is the antonym of *new* in every context.

"But should it be avoided in this context anyway?" Yes.

---

[EDIT]
The adjective applies to time (indirect, elided reference) rather than the noun mentioned (person). As such, it can be used only where its reference is unambiguously to time. "My old friend" has the elision: "My old **(-time)** friend". Not all contexts are self-explanatory and can be ambiguous, as in "My old teacher" occurring without context.

Comment: Kris, I have to say that it was quite a common expression for *former* where I grew up (New York State) as in: "When I went back for my class reunion I got to see many of my old teachers." Also [here it is used in a book](http://books.google.com/books?id=wEbG_tpO22kC&pg=PA246&dq=%22my+old+teacher%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iPfwUJXqDYmQ2gXEyIHwCw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22my%20old%20teacher%22&f=false)

Comment: @Jim "When I went back for my class reunion I got to see many of my old teachers." refers to teachers *of the old* (earlier times) not the *previous* (as opposed to *current*). So is the use of *old teacher* in the book as well.

Comment: I guess I don't see any difference between *previous* and *of an earlier time* because I don't interpret *previous* to mean exactly one prior, it could be any one of my former teachers.  Could you explain how you see it as different?

Comment: You did say it, though you didn't see it.:)

Comment: @Jim "I don't interpret previous to mean exactly one prior, it could be any one of my former teachers." Whereas *old* can mean only the one that belongs to a time long past and effectively excludes the sense of the *prior*.

Comment: Well, I still don't see it :-) but, given that it is permissible to use *old* when you mean *from an earlier time* then it *can* mean something other than *aged* (and by *aged* I am assuming you mean '*of advanced years*')

Comment: The insistence by @Kris that "previous" can only mean immediately prior rather ignores the fact that the OP asked asked about previous or former. My former students referred to me as their "old teacher" long before the second meaning (aged) was applicable.

Comment: @Fortiter "only mean immediately prior" is a hasty conclusion. See edit.

Comment: @Kris argues that when I was called "my old teacher", my former students meant "my old-time teacher". Perhaps they did, unless they were devotees of "old-time dancing". I will now retire to the bench beside coleopterist. I am feeling old.